# How to read the subject of an email using AppleScript

Tags: email, applescript

How to read the subject of an email using AppleScript?
I'm on Mail 16, AppleScript 2.8 .

This script is triggered by a rule in Mail app.
It DOES get triggered and it SHOULD get the subject of an email, and just display it.
I get my first dialog displaying "here" , but then nothing else and no errors giving me a hint as to why not.

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
        tell application "Mail"
                        display dialog length of these_messages as text
                       (* displays a 1, as there is 1 message *) 
            repeat with an_email in these_messages
                                display dialog "here"
                                (* displays 'here', so we know we are inside the loop *) 
                set subs to subject of an_email 
                display dialog subs as rich text
                                (* nothing is displyed, no error shows *) 
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

All exmaples Ive seen for this code should work, but most of them have been from 2015 and earlier. Maybe this isn't supposed to work anymore?

Comment: At least delete `as rich text`, a subject is already `text`. And this might be even the failure reason.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I had tried it without the as rich text. I had forgot the subject type is text.  Still same results, not a thing.